# problems using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, axios, mern

im programming a bootcamp on MERN, i have a problem with the react hooks, the problem say 'React Hook "useEffect" is called in function "signup" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function.' But i used correctly the react hook library, this is my code

```
import axios from "axios"
import {useEffect} from 'react'
export default function signup(){

        useEffect(() =>{
          axios.get('http://localhost:27017/bootcamp/pruebas')
          .then(response => console.log(response))
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
        }, []);
  return(
    <>
    <div className="min-h-full flex items-center justify-center py-12 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
      <div className="max-w-md w-full space-y-8">
        <div>
          <img
            className="mx-auto h-12 w-auto"
            src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/1880/1880988.png"
            alt="Workflow"
          />
          <h2 className="mt-6 text-center text-3xl font-extrabold text-gray-900">Create a new account</h2>
        </div>
        <form className="mt-8 space-y-6" action="#" method="POST">
          <input type="hidden" name="remember" defaultValue="true" />
          <div className="rounded-md shadow-sm -space-y-px">
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="email-address" className="sr-only">
                Email address
              </label>
              <input
                id="email-address"
                name="email"
                type="email"
                autoComplete="email"
                required
                className="appearance-none rounded-none relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 rounded-t-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm"
                placeholder="Email address"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="password" className="sr-only">
                Password
              </label>
              <input
                id="password"
                name="password"
                type="password"
                autoComplete="current-password"
                required
                className="appearance-none rounded-none relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 rounded-b-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm"
                placeholder="Password"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
          </div>
          <div>
            <button
              type="submit"
              className="group relative w-full flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500"
            >
              <span className="absolute left-0 inset-y-0 flex items-center pl-3">
              </span>
              Create!
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </>
)
}
```

on their code use a dependency with axios to create a CRUD and use a react hook library to use a method POST.

Comment: React hooks can only be called from React function components and other custom React hooks. `signup` is an invalid React component name, it should be capitalized, i.e. `Signup`.

Comment: they solve my problem, thanks

Answer (score 0):

User defined components must be capitalized. Refer React documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized).

So your component should look something like this.

```js
import axios from "axios"
import {
  useEffect
} from 'react'
export default function SignUp() {

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:27017/bootcamp/pruebas')
      .then(response => console.log(response))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }, []);
  return (
    <>JSX goes here</>
  )
}
```